# Create table with certain value for data range

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to create table like this:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 0.1 |
| ... | 0.1 |
| 2021-01-31 | 0.1 |
| 2021-02-01 | 0.5 |
| ... | 0.5 |
| 2021-02-28 | 0.5 |

So that in chosen data ranges I have certain values.
Could you tell me how to implement it in SQL?

Comment: I'd usually say use a recursive cte. But does Bigquery have it? Otherwise, create a calendar help table, and outer join. (That calendar table might be useful in many cases.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the rows by unnesting `generate_date_array()`.  Then assign the values using a `case` expression:

```
select date,
       (case when date_trunc(date, month) = date '2021-01-01' then 0.1
             when date_trunc(date, month) = date '2021-02-01' then 0.5
        end) as value 
from unnest(generate_date_array(date '2021-01-01', date '2021-02-28')) date;
```

If your date ranges don't match months, then use `case` expressions.

If you want a more general solution, you can define the date ranges explicitly and use:

```
with ranges as (
      select date '2012-01-01' as start_date, date '2012-01-31' as end_date, 0.1 as value
      union all
      select '2012-02-01' as start_date, '2012-02-28' as end_date, 0.1 as value
)    
select date, r.value
from ranges r cross join
     unnest(generate_date_array(r.start_date, r.end_date, interval 1 day)) date
```